# Excel - How do I filter by "word contained"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

I have data in the following format:

[image]

I would like to filter or pivot filter by every unique word in the list. I know how to retrieve a list of unique words, like so:

[image]

so I have that data. But how do I filter by all these values. I want to see a report of all the Popularity and Price summed up for each of these words. This of course implies overlapping, as "Bike Parts" data would affect both Bike and Parts numbers. Thoughts? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your ultimate question, use a `=SUMIF` formula.

To get this all automated, use VBA with a combination of text-to-columns, remove duplicates and the `=SUMIF` formula.

I was able to create the desired results with the following, although getting a sum of the Popularity seems odd...

```
Sub test1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim sRange As Range

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Columns("F:H").ClearContents

Range("A2:A" & lRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("F2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("F:F").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=" ", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set sRange = Range("G1")
sRange.Select

While Selection.End(xlDown).Value <> ""

sRange.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(lRow - 1, 0)).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("F2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Set sRange = sRange.Offset(0, 1)
sRange.Select

Wend

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Columns("F:F").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$F$" & lRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Range("F2").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "=SUMIF($A:$A,""*""&$F2&""*"",$B:$B)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Style = "Percent"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "=SUMIF($A:$A,""*""&$F2&""*"",$C:$C)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Style = "Currency"

Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(lRow - 2, 2)).FillDown

Range("F1").Value = Range("A1").Value
Range("G1").Value = Range("B1").Value
Range("H1").Value = Range("C1").Value

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. though I'd need it to support additional columns dynamically, not only three and I don't need sums I need averages. 

I realize I said sums above and that is my mistake, I can solve that. Any ideas on the dynamic thing tho?

Comment: change the `SUMIF` to `AVEAGEIF` and it should work for the averages.  To do dynamically, use a `While` loop, referencing the column headers you need averages.  i.e. `Range("B1").select....While activecell <> ""`, etc.  Reference the `While` loops in the above code

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. :)